# my form not submitting so where is the problem

Tags: reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-hooks

as you see my form not submit i can't see where is the problem i search but all the solution i found i already made it so what else can be the problem when i try to use console it don't show like it doesn't enter the submit function at all

this is the pieces in my component that work with form

```
const [editMyText, setEditMyText] = useState({
    editIsActive: false,
    textValue: body,
  });

  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const handleSaveEdit = (e) => {
    setEditMyText({
      editIsActive: false,
      textValue: inputRef.current.value,
    });
    // updatePost(_id, textValue);
  };

  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('done 1');
    updatePost(_id, textValue);
    console.log('done 2');
  };

 {body !== null && !editIsActive ? (
              <p
                className='card-text'
                onClick={(e) => auth.user._id === user && handleEditText(e)}
              >
                {textValue}
              </p>
            ) : (
              <form           
                className='edit-post-form'
                onSubmit={(e) => handleOnSubmit(e)}
              >
                <textarea
                  className='edit-text'
                  defaultValue={textValue}
                  ref={inputRef}
                />

                <button
                  className='btn btn-raised btn-danger mr-2'
                  onClick={(e) => handleCloseEdit(e)}
                >
                  Close
                </button>
                <button
                  type='submit'
                  className='btn btn-raised btn-success'
                  onClick={(e) => handleSaveEdit(e)}
                >
                  Save
                </button>
              </form>
            )}
```

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but the problem may be caused by `onClick` handler applied to button. Try to remove it and submit a form, here's some overhead in submission logic. Submit button does exactly what it has to do - it call `onSubmit` event on your form, there's no need to handle click on it.

Comment: yes i figure it out now i moved the action that happen from button click to form submit and it work , thanks alot